Avoiding Inertia Links navigation in a Sidebar when clicking again on current page
In a ReactJS + Inertia + Laravel webapp, I have a Sidebar component with several Links that change between the different pages of my application.
I notice that when being, let's say in Home page, if I click again on the Home button in the sidebar, the page transitions fires again, and so the application does a new request to Laravel, re-rendering the Home component.
I am not telling this is a problem, as this is the normal behaviour of Inertia Links. I am simply wondering how could I avoid that specific navigations to the same page.
Thanks in advance.
